# Purge command not executing

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

From the code below, my Discord bot would not delete any messages, neither does it give any errors about the command.

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def clean(ctx, *, args):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=args + 1)
    await ctx.send('Cleared by {}'.format(ctx.author.mention))
    time.sleep(2)
    await ctx.channel.purge(1)
```

Comment: `time.sleep` is blocking, it's better to use `await asyncio.sleep` instead

Comment: dude you should post that answer! @nonimportant it's correct though lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you use `time.sleep` which is blocking. It is better to use `ascyncio.sleep` instead, as it isn't blocking, and will let the rest of your code run. In addition, all of the parameters in `ctx.channel.purge` function are keyword-only, so the last line in the command would be another reason as to why the command isn't working.
Also, the bare asterisk in your parameters isn't needed and is redundant.

However, the main problem is that the `args` parameter is a `str`, not an `int`,  needed for the `ctx.channel.purge` function and addition. You can make the parameter an `int` by adding a type hint for the `args` parameter or explicitly converting it to an `int`.

With using type hints:

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def clean(ctx, args: int):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=args + 1)
    await ctx.send(f"Cleared by {ctx.author.mention}")
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
```

With explicit type conversion/casting:

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def clean(ctx, args):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=int(args) + 1)
    await ctx.send(f"Cleared by {ctx.author.mention}")
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to define what type `args` is, and for your last purge line, you need to set `limit=1`. Try this out:

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def clean(ctx, args : int):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=args + 1)
    await ctx.send('Cleared by {}'.format(ctx.author.mention))
    time.sleep(2)
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your parameter to clear messages is using `args`, which would be trying to use a string number, however you would need to be using an integer in order to purge the set amount of messages.

I've just cleaned up your code and fixed the issue, currently if the user doesn't include a specified amount, it would automatically clear a set messages of `5`. When the user includes an amount to clear, it would as long as the amount is an `int`. I've also omitted lines that doesn't help from your code.

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def clean(ctx, amount=5):
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)
```